# How to calculate minimum excludant from graph for different permutation?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph, tree

This is practice problem in codechef. For complete [question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREEMX)

What I have done so far is, created a graph from list of tuples

(Ex: `input_list = [(1,2),(2,3)]`)

And taken all permutations for the set of `input_list` and passing each permutation to `process()`. In `process()`, iterating over each element and calculating **MEX** of that.

**Definition of MEX:**

> Minimum Excludant(MEX) is the smallest non-negative integer not
>   included in given set of numbers.

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations


class Graph:
    """ Graph is data structure(directed). """


    def __init__(self, connections):
        """ Initializing graph with set as default value. """
        self._graph = defaultdict(set)
        self.add_connections(connections)

    def add_connections(self, connections):
        """ Add connections(list of tupules) to graph. """
        for node1, node2 in connections:
            self.add(node1,node2)

    def add(self, node1, node2):
        """ Add node1 and node2 to graph which is initialized with set by default. """
        self._graph[node1].add(node2)
        self._graph[node2].add(node1)

    def get_graph(self):
        return dict(self._graph)


def mex(arr_set):
    mex = 0
    while mex in arr_set:
        mex+=1
    return mex


def process(graph, order):
    a_p = [0] * len(order)
    for i, el in zip(range(len(order)), order):
        a_p[i] = mex(graph[el])
    return a_p


t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    v = int(input())
    e = []
    for i in range(v-1):
        e.append(tuple(map(int, input().split())))

    g = Graph(e)
    print(g.get_graph())
    all_vertices = {s for i in e for s in i}
    result = []
    for p in permutations(all_vertices, v):
        out = process(g.get_graph(), p)
        print("{} --> {}".format(p, out))
        result.append(out) if out not in result else None

    print(len(result))
```

I'm struck at calculating in **MEX**.

I didn't get why I'm not getting right results.

Please explain where I'm getting wrong in my code to get desired output?

Any suggestion to my improve my code are welcome.

**Rules of problem:**

You have a tree **T** with n vertices. Consider an ordering `P=(v_1,…,vn)` of vertices of **T**. We construct a sequence `A(P)=(a1,…,an)` using the following process:

- Set all `ai=−1`.
- Process vertices in order `v1,…,vn`. For the current vertex vi set
  `ai=MEX(au1,…,auk)`, where `u1,…,uk` is the set of neighbours of `vi`.

**Unexpected results:**

```
1
3
1 2
2 3
{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2}}
(1, 2, 3) --> [0, 0, 0] # should be (0, 1, 0)
(1, 3, 2) --> [0, 0, 0]
(2, 1, 3) --> [0, 0, 0]
(2, 3, 1) --> [0, 0, 0] # should be (1, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 2) --> [0, 0, 0]
(3, 2, 1) --> [0, 0, 0]
1
```

**Explanation of result:**

(I have taken (2,3,1) combination for explanation)

In the order `(2,3,1)` we process `v2` first. So

- Setting `i=2`, we first observe that `v2` has neighbors `v1` and
  `v3`. As both `a1` and `a3` are at their initialized state `(=−1)`,
  we set

  `a2=mex{−1,−1}=0`.
- We then set `i=3`. The vertex `v3` has a `v2` as its sole neighbor.
  As `a2=0` the algorithm tells us to set

  `a3=mex{0}=1`.
- The last node to be processed is `a1`. The only neighbod of `v1` is
  `v2`, and currently `a2=0`. So the algorithm tells us to set

  `a1=mex{0}=1`.

So, output is `P(2, 3, 1) ==> A(P)= (a1, a2, a3) = (1, 0, 1)` but I'm getting `(0, 0, 0)` for all values.

Comment: Please tell the reason for downvote. I will improve question. If this is not a right platform to ask this question. Please suggest right platform to ask this kind of question. I will delete from here.

Comment: I did not downvote you but I see two weaknesses of your question. First, you do not explain the problem you are solving (MEX) but just give a link to a description. Such links are frowned upon here since that means extra work for would-be answerers. Such links can also become stale and your question would then be impossible to understand. Second, your actual question to us is "Please explain how to complete that `mex` function" and "any suggestion to my improve my code are welcome." That is very broad and vague.

Comment: Therefore, please include a full (if perhaps shortened) explanation of your problem *in your question*. Also be more clear what is wrong with your code and what you are asking us.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for guiding to make question more precise. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "process" function is not doing what it should. You should initialize the `a_p`'s at `-1` and assign to a_i the mex of the a_p corresponding to the neighbours rather than to their indices. (Exactly like in your explanation of the rules)

Like that:

```
def process(graph, order):
    a_p = [-1] * len(order)
    for el in order:
        a_p[el-1] = mex([a_p[u-1] for u in graph[el]])
    return a_p
```

PS: You can (should?) use `enumerate(L)` instead of `zip(range(len(L)), L)`.

Comment: Getting `IndexError: list index out of range`. Why this `[a_p[u] for u in graph[el]]`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot a -1 while changing the function. "[a_p[u] for u in graph[el]]" is because we want to take the mex of the a_i corresponding to the neighbours, not the mex of the neighbours index. So if the  neighbours are 1 and 3 for example, we want the mex of {a_1,a_3} not the mex of {1,3}.